# Executing "simple" sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Here is data in my table :

```
id      name       surname       place
1       test1         isdad      YES
2       test2       spreda       YES
3       test3          me        NO
4       test4      smallvile     YES
```

What I'd like to get, all ids where place='YES'. So Ids are

```
1
2
4
```

and the result count is 3. I want to append that number to the end of the results, so the result should look like this:

```
1
2
4
3
```

Comment: So ... exactly what has been tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "their count(or sum) is 3"? Do you just want a final row added with the total number of previous rows?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to the count added as the last record?

Comment: This is not possible in single query

Comment: @Nishant It actually is possible: see `UNION` (hint, hint) for instance. However, I refuse to answer such a lackluster unloved question :(

Comment: @pst I've tried select id, count(*) but it doesn't give me the total count at the end

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You could theoretically create a temp table and dump the results of your `SELECT`/`WHERE` query into it, then `SELECT` the ids from that table and `UNION` it with the `COUNT` of all records. But this brings back a mixed dataset that doesn't even make sense

Comment: @Teddy Yes I want total count as the last record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost definitely a better way to do this. That said, you could do:

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE place = 'YES'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE place = 'YES'
```

`UNION ALL` will append the result number as a new row rather than attempting to add it as another column.

Please don't do this; the results will be mixed, it stands in stalwart defiance of good software design and will be baffling to anyone who comes along later and has to work on this piece of code.

Comment: Or `SELECT id, 1 as is_id FROM myTable WHERE place = 'YES'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), 0 as is_id FROM myTable WHERE place = 'YES'`. I agree that it's messy.

Comment: What are the `1` and `0` values doing there? That just makes the results even more baffling and difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can do something similar to this in a single query using `WITH ROLLUP`:

```
select id, count(*) 
from myTable
where place='YES'
group by id 
with rollup
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE place='YES'
```

will return with the ids what you want, and the rowcount will store the count number, if you use this with php or c++/c#

Comment: Except it has nothing to do with _php or c++/c#_.